# Using uniq to compare 2 dictionaries

Tags: linux, bash, dictionary, terminal, uniq

So I have two dictionaries to compare (american english vs british english).

How do I use the uniq command to count (-c) how many words are in the american english or british english but not both?

Also how do I count the number of word occurrences of one dictionary that appears in a  different dictionary?

Just trying to understand how uniq works on a more complicated level. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `grep` will help here. To find common word use `grep -f american_dict british_dict | wc -l`. To get the other results, You can play with -v option of grep.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `uniq`, use the `comm` command for this. It finds lines that are in common between two files, or are unique to one or the other.

This counts all the words that are in one dictionary but not both

```
comm -3 american british | wc -l
```

This counts the words that are in both dictionaries:

```
comm -12 american british | wc -l
```

By default, `comm` shows the lines that are only in the first file in column 1, the lines that are only in the second file in column 2, and the lines in both files in column 3. You can then use the `-[123]` options to tell it to leave out the specified columns. So `-3` only shows columns 1 and 2 (the unique words in each file), while `-12` only shows column 3 (the common words).

It requires that the files be sorted, which I assume your dictionary files are.

You can also do it with unique. It has options `-u` to show only lines that appear once, and `-d` to show only lines that are repeated.

```
sort american british | uniq -u | wc -l # words in just one language
sort american british | uniq -d | wc -l # words in both languages
```

Comment: You can use process substitution. Instead of `american british`, use `<(sort american) <(sort british)`. If you don't understand that, it's explained in the bash manual. http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Process-Substitution.html#Process-Substitution

Comment: Thanks for your help Barmar I understand now.